# i can't open, ping,.. any domain after upgrade debian

Tags: debian, dns, dnsmasq, avahi

after upgrade debian i cannot open or ping any domain even in firefox (but i havnt any problem via proxy).

for example wget:

unable to resolve host address ‘google.com’

but i can work with ip (add in /etc/hosts) or dig any domian

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> debian.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 35527
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;debian.org.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
debian.org.     45  IN  A   149.20.20.22
debian.org.     45  IN  A   5.153.231.4
debian.org.     45  IN  A   140.211.15.34
debian.org.     45  IN  A   130.89.148.14
debian.org.     45  IN  A   128.31.0.62

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Jun 01 09:03:52 IRDT 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 119
```

i also can access to ip directly or access to domain with /etc/hosts

my /etc/resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1 
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

and my /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
#dns=dnsmasq
[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

when i run `nmcli dev show | grep IP4.DNS`:

```
IP4.DNS[1]:                             127.0.0.1
IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.8.8
```

apparently every thing is ok but i cannot access to any domain directly.

Any help with this would be best appreciated!

Comment: What's your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` look like for the `hosts:` line?

Comment: `hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns`

Comment: does `getent hosts google.com` work?

Comment: no, not working  but when i put in `/etc/hosts` working

Comment: This is... a head scratcher. Are you using nscd, unscd, or similar? Also, in case it matters, which local DNS cache are you using?

Comment: i tried without nscd, with nscd and with unscd + nscd but not response

Comment: You've got 127.0.0.1 as a name server—that probably means you have a local DNS cache running. Which program is that (e.g., dnsmasq, bind, ...)?

Comment: this is dns apkages: http://pastebin.com/XsC31zQq and all pacages: http://pastebin.com/sWUyWy93

Comment: You could try getting rid of dnsmasq, although I really doubt it's the problem since your dig output appears to show it working. Do you have any firewall rules? Anything else weird, like do you maybe not have the lo interface up (not sure if that would cause a problem like this)? And odd configuration on this machine? [At this point, you've checked everything I can think of that'd cause this, other than firewall rules—hoping to stumble across a "hey, that's weird, it shouldn't be like that..."]

Comment: tnx a lor dear  derobert. i reinstalled all package with apt but any change. 
finally after install squid i can access to network via firefox and some other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have the line `nameserver 127.0.0.1` as the first option? You can put it after primary dns like `8.8.8.8`.
Again, in your `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, try to set

```
dns=default
```

Comment: dig shows that 127.0.0.1 is working...

Comment: tanks for replay, but no problem not fixed